# Can we have graphical server on ttyS*

Tags: amazon-web-services, qt, serial-port, framebuffer, tty

I have a "c5.2xlarge" AWS EC2 instance running an application. Upon system starting, we perform some initial setup. This starter page uses JavaScript and QT for its application. We also use the same program on a virtual machine.It functions perfectly there. I am connecting to this instance using EC2 serial console option(ttyS0).

While the starting page functions flawlessly on a VMware instance, it is not functional on an AWS instance.

I know that

1. ttyS%d are hardware serial ports. The devices are likely
   preallocated and may not necessarily correspond to existing serial
   hardware.
2. tty%d (numeric suffix, with no letter between, starting from 1) are
   all "virtual consoles" which have no specific designated purpose.
   These can be text terminals, or a graphical server can be launched
   on top of the text terminal.

The frame buffer driver for console is availble on both the platfroms (AWS and vmware)

```
[root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]# dmesg | grep frame
[    0.336865] vesafb: framebuffer at 0xfe400000, mapped to 0xffffc90000800000, using 3072k, total 3072k
[    0.336893] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[    0.383742] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48

[root@xxxxx ~]# lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:01.3 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
        Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
        Kernel modules: i2c_piix4
00:03.0 VGA compatible controller: Amazon.com, Inc. Device 1111
00:04.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Amazon.com, Inc. Device 8061
        Subsystem: Amazon.com, Inc. Device 0000
        Kernel driver in use: nvme

    
[root@xxxxx ~]# dmesg | grep 00:03.0
[    0.370142] pci 0000:00:03.0: [1d0f:1111] type 00 class 0x030000
[    0.370699] pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfe400000-0xfe7fffff pref]
[    0.372784] pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfebe0000-0xfebeffff pref]
[    0.396222] vgaarb: setting as boot device: PCI:0000:00:03.0
[    0.396223] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:03.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.396225] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:03.0
[    0.410772] pci 0000:00:03.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
```

The same works on the virtual console, however I'm not sure if this is supported on serail ports (ttyS%d). Has anyone attempted to use the AWS serial port console to run a QT-based application?

Comment: Using a Qt-based web browser with graphics on an AWS serial port console isn't straightforward due to the limitations of the serial port console environment. The AWS serial port console is primarily intended for low-level access to instances, especially for troubleshooting or recovery purposes. It doesn't support graphics or sophisticated user interfaces like those provided by Qt-based web browsers.